# First derivative of a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

This question was featured on my calculus mid-term today :

Find the first derivative of $g(x,y)$ where :

---

$$ 
g(x,y) = f(x^2  + y^2 ,xy)
$$

---

This is the exact text of the problem. I just don't get it. How are we supposed to find the first derivative of a function that has no expression ? Secondly, how cand I find the derivative when we don't know in respect with which variable to differentiate ?

Can somebody please explain and show a solution ?

Comment: This seems a typo. Perhaps the proper formula is $g(x,y)=(x^2+y^2,xy)$. If not, $f$ should be defined somewhere, or, at least, some conditions about $f$ should be given.

Comment: No typo on my part, that's why I can't understand the problem. Our professor mentioned we should somehow express the derivative $g(x,y)$ in terms of $f$ . Does this make any sense at all ? Because it sure doesn't to me.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the "derivative" of a function $h: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is the $n \times m$ Jacobian matrix (denoted $Dh$) consisting of all partial derivatives of all the components of $h$.

In your case, $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, so its derivative is $$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 2x f_x(x^2+y^2, xy) + y f_y(x^2 + y^2, xy) & 2y f_x(x^2 + y^2, xy) + x f_y(x^2 + y^2, xy)\end{array}\right)$$ Here $f_x$ and $f_y$ denote the partial derivatives of $f$, and I have used the chain rule to take the partial derivatives of the composite function $g(x, y) = f(x^2+y^2, xy)$.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems incomplete to me.
You can find its partial derivative with respect to x or y. But it should be mentioned that with respect to which variable you should take the derivative